# Interactive ggplot2 heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly, r-plotly

```
library(dplyr)

Apartment_no <- c("1-SV","1-SV","1-SV","1-SH","1-SH","1-SH","1-1V","1-1V","1-1V",
                  "1-1H","1-1H","1-1H","3-SV","3-SV","3-SV","3-1V","3-1V","3-1V",
                  "3-1H","3-1H","3-1H")

month <- c("September","October","November","September","October","November",
            "September","October","November","September","October","November",
            "September","October","November","September","October","November",
            "September","October","November")

Days <- c(19,19,28,2,19,28,2,19,28,2,19,28,25,31,28,12,29,24,8,26,19)

Heat_clean <- data.frame(Apartment_no,month,Days)
```

I am given the data in the above format & I have made a ggplot2 heat map out of it using the following code:

```r
Heat_clean %>% 
    mutate(color = case_when(Days <= 5 ~ "blue", 
                             Days <= 15 ~ "orange", 
                             Days <= 25 ~ "pink", 
                             is.na(Days) ~ "red", 
                             TRUE ~ "green")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(month,Apartment_no)) +      
        geom_tile(aes(fill=color),color="white") + 
        scale_fill_identity()
```

Is there a way to make that interactive? I know that we define call it arbitarily using p and then we can use

```
plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

But I am actually perplexed where can it be added in this case to make it interactive.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. you can definitely assign that ggplot2 visualization to a variable `p` and use `plotly::ggplotly(p)` to convert it to a interactive visualization. Where are you having trouble at?

Comment: @yifyan, I am not sure, where can I add that thing in the above code because it's giving me an error & how can I activate my legends i.e I want the color conditions of my Days as my legends.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error. Can you add error messages or screenshots?

Comment: @yifyan, I used following code, > Heat_clean %>% mutate(color = case_when(Days <= 5 ~ "blue", Days <= 15 ~ "orange", Days <= 25 ~ "pink", is.na(Days) ~ "red", TRUE ~ "green")) %>% p %>% ggplot(aes(month,Apartment_no)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=color),color="white")+scale_fill_identity()

>plotly::ggplotly(p)                                                                                                           The error is "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 31 needed but only 21 provided.". However it works fine If I remove "p%>%" from the above code. I just want to make it interactiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not fully clear to me what you are seeking here, but we can make the `ggplot` object *"interactive"*, as you call it, using `ggplotly`;

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```

```r
Heat_clean %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(Days <= 5 ~ "blue", 
                           Days <= 15 ~ "orange", 
                           Days <= 25 ~ "pink", 
                           is.na(Days) ~ "red", 
                           TRUE ~ "green")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month,Apartment_no)) +      
    geom_tile(aes(fill=color),color="white") + 
    scale_fill_identity() %>%
  ggplotly(.)
```

[image]

Or you can make your heatmap in `plotly` directly;

```r
Heat_clean %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(Days <= 5 ~ 1, 
                           Days <= 15 ~ 2, 
                           Days <= 25 ~ 3, 
                           is.na(Days) ~ 4, 
                           TRUE ~ 5),
         color = as.factor(color)) %>% 
  plot_ly(z = .$color, 
          x = .$month, 
          y = .$Apartment_no, 
          type = "heatmap", showscale=FALSE, colorscale ="Viridis")
```

[image]